# Redirect using Java Jersey rest filters

Tags: java, jersey, single-sign-on, jersey-2.0, rest

I am trying to request a new call from the request pre-matching filter. I need to initiate the new request from the start so that this new requested will again go through the filters and route to a different process.

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class SSOFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException 
    {
        URI ssoUri = null;
        try 
        {
            String requestedQueryString = requestContext.getUriInfo().getRequestUri().getQuery();
            ssoUri = new URI(requestContext.getUriInfo().getBaseUri()+"/saml/SSO?"+ requestedQueryString);
        } 
        catch (URISyntaxException e) 
        {
            Debug.println(Debug.ERROR, "Error encountered in generating SSO URI " + e.getMessage());
        }
        Response.status(Status.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT).location(ssoUri).build();
    }
}
```

I want this call to happen only on the server so that browser shouldn't be aware of what's happening here, Also the browser URL shouldn't update.

Comment: Use requestContext.abortWith(Response)

Comment: requestContext.abortWith(Response) will send the response to the browser which will update the URL in the browser.